# Accessing this type of Json object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm receiving the following JSON response and i want to access its elements and print the message to the page.

for example, **I want print out trucks:** *Id 1,description: lovely truck etc..*

```
var response= json.data.filter(item => item.success).map(function (d) {
                                return {
                                 success: d.request.trucks
                                }
                            })
```

Here is my JSON Object

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "cars": [],
  "boats": [],
  "bikes": [],
  "trucks": [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "description": [
        "lovely truck!"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "description": [
        "lovely truck! xx"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

let's say the JSON object is stored to the variable d so it will be access like this:

```
var res1= d.trucks[0].id; // returns 1
var res2 = d.trucks[0].description; // returns lovely trucks
 console.log(res1);//shows in console
 console.log(res2);
//you can print to the here by using
 $("#msg").text(res1);
```

To learn more about json objects visit: 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please what's wrong in the answer?, can you give more detail to the question and error received?

Comment: Hey @GeniusGeek, i didnt downvote your answer. I tried accessing  trucks[0].id I get 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined'

Comment: Okay, How are you accessing it? Also try using JSON.parse() method so response could be converted to javascript object like this obj= JSON.parse(d); then access it using obj.trucks[0].Id